# jQuery 3.2.1 - delegate() - Dynamically created button, delegate() firing on entire document instead of element

Tags: jquery

Having some trouble understanding why this is happening. I've got a button that is dynamically created. I need to be able to click that button to trigger something else. In JQuery 3.2.1, delegate is supposed to follow this format.

```
$(document).delegate('button.new', 'click', function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

This does actually fire the alert() when I click on the button. However, it also fires the alert when I click on literally anything else on the page because of the $(document) part I'm guessing.

Is it possible there is an issue with delegate() in this version of jQuery? It is definitely not possible to upgrade jQuery version, so I have work within the confines of what version 3.2.1 offers.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

`delegate()` was deprecated in 3x.  http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

You should use `on()` instead.  http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.new', function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

Take note that the position of the event and the child selector swapped.

Comment: Actually, I've tried on.('click') and it's doing the same thing. The entire 'document' is the trigger instead of just the button. I switched back to delegate but I do see now that it's deprecated. But yeah, still getting that same issue where the document is being the trigger. So I can literally click in the margins of the page, and it's triggering the alert.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that this was working as intended, but I had to read some of the finer details of `.on()` to understand why this wasn't working.

I ended up having to wrap that dynamically created button in another div and then target that wrapping div, rather than `document` or `body` as I've found in other solutions. Otherwise the outside element is always the trigger rather than the dynamically created button.

```
    // Button that I wanted created after another button is clicked
    resultsBtn = '<button class="btn btn-secondary see-results">See Results</button>';

    // An empty div is inserted
    btnGroup.append('<div class="btn-wrap"></div>');

    // Click event that creates the button
    btnNo.click(function(){

      // Inserting the button into the empty div
      $('.btn-wrap').append(resultsBtn);
    });

    // Targeting the button inside the empty div 
    $('.btn-wrap').on('click', seeResults, function(){
      alert('test');
    });
```

Hopefully that makes sense.